# FFmpeg drops HLS frames

Tags: ffmpeg, stream, http-live-streaming

I'm trying to start `ffmpeg`

```
vlad@s1:~/hls/first$ ffmpeg -re -i http://86.57.225.238:8090 -c:v copy -c:a copy index.m3u8
```

But `ffmpeg` doesn't start. What is a problem?

```
Input #0, mpegts, from 'http://86.57.225.238:8090':
  Duration: N/A, start: 88845.286311, bitrate: N/A
  Program 1 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Bel_4 Mogilev
      service_provider: Bel_4 Mogilev
    Stream #0:0[0xc9]: Video: h264 (Main) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p, 720x576 [SAR 12:11 DAR 15:11], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0xca]: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 224 kb/s
Output #0, hls, to 'index.m3u8':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p, 720x576 [SAR 12:11 DAR 15:11], q=2-31, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 25 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, 224 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=00:00:41.35 bitrate=N/A
```

Comment: What do you wish to do? Save the original playlist with references to localized segments? ffmpeg can't do that. Save the entire media data? It can do that if you output to a single TS file.

Comment: @Mulvya no. i want start broadcast tv channel from http://86.57.225.238:8090 to my  local network without encoding. with encoding all ok